# Symfony2 how to get query of last request

Tags: sql, symfony

I'm looking for an entity by 3 properties like that:

```
$seasonstart = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['seasondatestart'].' 00:00:00');
$seasonend  = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['seasondateend'].' 00:00:00');

$rep_season = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('xxx:Season');
$season = $rep_season->findBy(array(
       'name' => $row['seasonname'],
       'start' => $seasonstart,
       'end' => $seasonend
));
```

while $row['seasondatestart'] is something like '2010-07-01'.

Now i want to know what actually happens here and debug the sql-query. How can i get the query string like "SELECT * FROM season WHERE name='...' AND ...". You know what i mean.

Your advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: I think you need to use `EntityRepository`, in which you can write a query manually and then get it for more analize

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the generated SQL queries, you can use the Web Debug Toolbar :

[image]

Simply click on it to see the full queries.